# Grease Pencil bug, drawing disapears when zooming and moving

Tags: grease-pencil

so I built a scene with different components ( a building and some trees), everything looks fine from distance, but when I zoom in or move in some directions, the trees get "cut", they partly disapear. ( stroke depth order is in 3d btw).
[image]

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that the trees and the building are in different collections.

Comment: What version of blender are you on? just asking cos i used to have the same problem with older versions (like 2.90) but i thought it was fixed since.